# How to Disable Or Override a dialogue box in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel vba code which opens another application from my pc and runs some task repeatedly. After completeing every tasks it shows a msgbox with OK and Cancel. I want to proceed with OK. What to do?
My code is here-

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Set DESKTOP = CreateObject("DESKTOP.APPLICATION")

Set app = DESKTOP.GETAPPLICATION("Teller,MB.LCY.CASHCHQ")

app.Visible = True
  
I = 2
  
CUST = Cells(I, 1).Value
   
   Do While CUST <> ""
    
        PROSTAT = Cells(I, 5).Value
        
        If PROSTAT = "" Then
        
        app.FUNC = "I"
        FTID = app.NewID
                          
        AC_NAME = Cells(I, 1).Value
        AC_NO = Cells(I, 2).Value
        DEBIT_AMOUNT = Cells(I, 3).Value
                
        app.Value("TRANSACTION.CODE") = "5"
        app.Value("CURRENCY.2") = "BDT"
        app.Value("TELLER.ID.1") = "1030"
        app.Value("AMOUNT.LOCAL.1") = DEBIT_AMOUNT
        app.Value("ACCOUNT.2") = AC_NO
        app.Value("NARRATIVE.2") = AC_NAME
        app.Value("CHEQUE.NUMBER") = AC_NAME
        app.COMMIT
               
        Cells(I, 4) = FTID
        Cells(I, 5).Value = "POSTED"
        
        End If
        
        I = I + 1
CUST = Cells(I, 1).Value

Loop

Set app = Nothing

Set DESKTOP = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: If the program doesn't give you a way to over-ride it, then you can't.

Comment: as braX says, but research if the program can accept an additional argument that suppresses the need for user interaction... often something like "-silent" or "-quiet" or "-noUI"

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Stax.

There might be a nasty cludge to determine the Window HANDLE of the dialog that has the OK button and send it a Mouse Click windows message, via the Win32 API. But (a) this is by no means straightforward, and (b) you'd need to find a way of doing it asynchronously (as I assume your VBA blocks until the "OK" is clicked).